# htaccess rule doesn't work - NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

This URL:

```
https://mqgmodas.com/rebajas/
```

Into the `.htaccess` I have:

```
Redirect 301 https://mqgmodas.com/rebajas/ https://masqguapas.com/rebajas/
```

Also I have a redirection in my control panel saying that `mqgmodas.com` must go to `masqguapas.com` (homepage redirection is working ok, but the subdomains/subfolders, no).

But when you search for "masqguapas" (at least in Spain), the 3rd & 4th results are URLs from the old domain... And the redirection isn't working. Google Chrome says *NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID*

[image: Error page]

Comment: And the old domain is `mqgmodas.com`? What do you mean "it's working from the main domain"?

Comment: @MrWhite I want to mean that homepage redirection is working ok, but the subdomains/subfolders, no. I'm taking a look to your answer and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

From the *browser* error you posted it looks like you don't have a valid SSL cert for the old domain. You will need to have a valid SSL cert for the old domain if you wish to redirect `https://olddomain.example` as otherwise, the *browser* won't allow the request to reach your server.